# AccountAuthenticator icons

Tags: android

I am implementing an [AbstractAccountAuthenticator](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AbstractAccountAuthenticator.html) and I cannot find any information regarding the dimensions of the **icon**, and **smallIcon** drawables required.

There is a [SampleSyncAdapter](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/SampleSyncAdapter/index.html) which is a sample demo for implementing the above (It also demonstrates how to implement an AbstractThreadedSyncAdapter), but it only defines 1 drawable resource for both **icon** and **smallIcon**.

Does anyone know the standard and required pixel sizes for both of these resources?

Comment: This seems to depend on the screen width, not screen density. I have given some clues about this here: [link](http://www.digigene.com/android/accounts-in-android-part-two/)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

For high-density screens (drawable-hdpi):

- smallIcon: 36x36 px
- normal: 72x72 px

for medium-density screens (drawable-mdpi):

- smallIcon: 24x24 px
- normal: 48x48 px

One drawable resource for both in /drawable is the default drawable resource, and it's designed for normal screen size and a medium density. The system scales default density resources up for high-density screens and down for low-density screens so it's better if you make a directory for hdpi and another one for mdpi with the given size of icons.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Check authenticator.xml and size of icons (ic_exchange_selected,ic_exchange_minitab_selected) in  [FROYO-QRD-GB-DSDS-7225](https://www.codeaurora.org/git/projects/qrd-gb-dsds-7225/repository/revisions/0c15e6aa7e51b42c5c0977389ffa5372c95ccb29/entry/packages/apps/Email/res/xml/authenticator.xml)

Comment: For other screen density (ldpi,xhdpi) you should follow the 3:4:6:8 scaling ratio. Check it in Android DevGuide [Alternative Drawables](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

Comment: More simply put, `smallIcon` is 24dp square, and `icon` is 48dp square.

Answer (score 0):

There is some ambiguity about what difference is between `icon` and `smallIcon`. [Android](https://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/creating-authenticator.html) declares that both of them refer to the icon at the left of the account label (android robot icon in this figure), but where the `smallIcon` is used instead of `icon` depends on the screen size. This definition does not seem to be exact in view of the following comparison:

[image]

The above compares icon and smallIcon in two devices with different screen widths. From the figure, it seems that android uses the smallIcon for the Accounts page (left screenshot in the above image). The larger icon is only used for the page showing the different accounts of an account type (right screenshot) in Note 4, whereas Nexus 5 displays the same icon size for both screens. As the screen widths of Nexus 5 and Note 4 are 388 dp and 445 dp respectively, screen width of 400 dp can be guessed as a threshold for the screen width above which the larger icon is applied. This is not exact, nevertheless.
I have addressed this topic as well as the whole android account authentication subject [here](http://www.digigene.com/android/accounts-in-android-part-two/)

Answer (score 0):

Following the specific provided by CsaByte i've ended up with this sizes for my Authenticator icons.

**mdpi**

- smallIcon: 24x24
- icon:      48x48

**hdpi**

- smallIcon: 36x36
- icon:      72x72

**xhdpi**

- smallIcon: 48x48
- icon:      96x96

**xxhdpi**

- smallIcon: 72x72
- icon:      144x144

**xxxhdpi**

- smallIcon: 96x96
- icon:      192x192

Put those drawables in their respective drawable-density folder.

Then in the authenticator.xml you can go with this:

```
<account-authenticator xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:accountType="@string/account_type"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:smallIcon="@drawable/smallIcon" />
```

The icon size is the same as the ic_launcher size, if you dont want waste space inside your app and you dont need a custom icon for your authenticator, you can use the mipmap ic_launcher instead. Your authenticator.xml can be written as:

```
<account-authenticator xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:accountType="@string/account_type"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:smallIcon="@drawable/smallIcon" />
```